# Why can't I setText?

Tags: android

[java screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNguM.png)
[You all seem skeptical but it seriously cannot display the text on the screen! PLease do help! xml screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJAPl.png)

Why can't I do setText to TextView?

I tried following tutorials but I still cant make it work...

```
public class quad_eqn_qsn1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quad_eqn_qsn1);

        textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quad_eqn1);
        textView.setText("WHY CANT I DO IT");
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.olevelemath.quad_eqn_qsn1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quad_eqn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean "you can' t do it?"

Comment: @Stultuske I mean that the text "WHY CANT I DO IT" is not displayed in the preview/emulator

Comment: No Error? try again with a [mcve]

Comment: So have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger? Is it executing at all?

Comment: first things first, put a place holder text and check if you can see that `android:text="place holder"`

Comment: on a side not, for god sake follow Java naming conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah all my activities work fine on my phone! Only the text is not displayed... If I use xml android:text="Hello", the "Hello" word pops up, but not when I use java

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu Yes I can!

Comment: @NickCardoso Yes I never said that there was an error, I just said that the text cannot be displayed on the screen! This is the most minimal I can put and the text is not displayed on the screen. I already deleted the non relevant ones.

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu Thanks for the advice, will definitely get lost next time if I never name them correctly

Comment: I have added the ss of XML and Java since you all seem skeptical.. why cant it display the text!

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. So the only one things that can be wrong is that in Manifest you launch deferent activity. Make sure that this activity have this intent filter.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".quad_eqn_qsn1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Or if this is not your first activity so don't forget to declate it in manifest.

Comment: What the point to downvote the answer if this is a only one problem that can be in case that the activity does not appear. I copypaste this code in android studio, and it's work fine.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, no problem there... I have a few activities already, and they all work fine on my phone... I don't think that it is the solution I am looking for ! Thanks for trying, though!

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I dont have enough reputation to up vote you!